# Unhashable type, removing duplicates from a collection but keep the entry order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

I'm looking to remove all duplicates of a collection based on a key or combination of keys.

Consider below list of dicts:

```
c = [ {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1, 'b':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':2, 'z':4}]
```

The desired output would remove duplicates based on key(s). For `a` removed duplicates output:

```
[ {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':2, 'z':4}]
```

For a hashable collection the below code has worked for me:

```
def dups(seq):
    seen = []
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.append(item)
    return seen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `OrderedDict`, but hash on the `frozenset`s of keys:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict((frozenset(d), d) for d in reversed(c))
uniq = list(o.values())[::-1]

print(uniq)
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'z': 4}]
```

I reverse `c` before passing it to the `OrderedDict`, and then reverse the values I extract. This ensures I drop duplicates, keeping the first one.

---

You can extend frozensets to your existing code, by hashing on frozensets of keys. Use a `set` for efficient lookup.

```
def dups(seq):
    seen = set()
    for item in seq:
        hashval = frozenset(item)
        if hashval not in seen:
            seen.add(hashval)
            yield item

uniq = list(dups(c))
print(uniq)
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'z': 4}]
```